# How to change TFS configuration, DefaultCollection from SQL Server Express to SQL Server on the same server

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I was installing TFS 2015 and was never given a chance to choose my database. I already had a SQL Server Enterprise installed and installation "wizard" proceeded to install SQL Server Express and then putting TFS database on it. I am not sure why it works this way, but is there any way to change this??

My TFS has nothing on it, I just installed it. I've read a lot of blogs about moving "Collection" from one DB to another, but I don't want to move the collection (it's empty and it's easy to do through admin console). I am trying to move the actual TFS' internal components from SQL Server Express to SQL Server **on the same server**.

***UPDATE:***

For anyone interested in knowing more about/how-to unconfigure TFS: [Unconfigure Team Foundation Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2017/09/25/unconfigure-team-foundation-server/)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `Tfs_Configuration` database SQL Express instance to your full SQL Server instance, then run [`TFSConfig RemapDBs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/ref/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs)

An alternative, since you don't have any data: Just unconfigure your app tier and rerun the configuration wizard. Use the advanced configuration wizard and you'll have the opportunity to specify a database instance.

It's also worth noting that you should be installing TFS 2018, not TFS 2015, unless you have a *very* good reason. 2015 is 3 years old and two major releases behind.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Just a follow-up: 1) this may sound silly, but if I just uninstall the TFS2015 installation, does this fix the issue? I know Visual Studio canNOT be easily uninstalled as it makes configuration changes and installs many different pieces with it. Not sure if the same is true in TFS. 2) You cannot open configuration wizard once you install TFS. How would you open it? If you click on installation media, options are a) UNinstall or b) repair

Comment: 3) " Just unconfigure your app tier ", I wish you provided some hints/instructions for this and also for opening up config again. 4) Also you asked, why 2015 and not 2018. While I'm very new to TFS, I know that other Microsoft products such as SQL Server, you'd be very wise to stick with a couple of year old product as their latest is filled with bugs and issues.

Comment: @LearnByReading Google "unconfigure app tier". If that's your only concern, install 2018, not 2015. TFS is incredibly stable and contains relatively few bugs. The number of new features and capabilities you'll have access to by using 2018 vs 2015 is worth it.